# UUID em laravel e eloquent

Tags: laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, uuid

Bem eu sei que no Laravel alguns novos UUID métodos foram adicionados neste pacote

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

mas que não seu como usar no eloquent, alguem pode me ajudar a saber como modifico o cambo id nas migrations para receber UUID? Como coloco para salvar UUID automaticamente ou vou ter que gerar toda vez que for cadastrar um registro na tabela? E eu trato o UUID igual o ID para passar entre rotas?

Como uso isso?

```
Str::uuid();
Str::orderedUuid();
```

Alguém me salva por favor?

Comment: Seu Laravel é esse que está na tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação do laravel pede pra você declarar (string) depois do igual da var como segue o exemplo:

```
$uuid = (string) Str::uuid();

dd($uuid); // return "891fcc8e-018e-43ed-b2cf-f8f98bca70d5"
```

Link da documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-uuid